# What happens when someone is subjected to extreme pain beyond any pain tolerance?

Tags: pain

What happens in extreme medical scenarios when a individual is subjected to extremes of pain far beyond any pain tolerance?

Comment: Can you include a link or quote for this definition of 'pain tolerance' from a peer-reviewed source? This study (https://www.jpain.org/article/S1526-5900(22)00031-1/fulltext) defines the phrase as "the maximum pain an individual is willing to tolerate".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144572/discussion-on-question-by-jeffrey-mace-what-happens-when-someone-is-subjected-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The full definition for pain tolerance provided by the link you gave is:

> The maximum intensity of a pain-producing stimulus that **a subject is willing to accept** in a given situation. [emphasis added]

In other words, a person's pain tolerance is how much pain a person will endure before they decide that they do not want to experience more pain. A person can absolutely experience more pain than this limit. I do not have any data to back it up, but it seems clear to me that most common response to exceeding this limit is to try and lessen the painful stimuli.

Comment: While this answers the question, it would be helpful if you can back your answer with some references or data.